# Android Studio keeps reverting my changes

Tags: android, xml

I need help with my Android Project. More specifically, I want to know why Android Studio keeps reverting my changes for some reason.

I first got an error in my XML file saying, "Apostrophe is not preceeded \"

So I fixed the error and cleaned my project - but the change was undone, and the same error popped up.

I even tried deleting the entire string resource to avoid it, but all changes were reverted, and the message popped up again.

Does anyone know what kind of ghost is pranking me right now?

Comment: See: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/04/08/why-cant-edit-manifest-android-studio.html (while I focus on the manifest, the same problem can happen with resources as well)

Comment: I had this problem, and it was a bit of a "derr" moment :)

I was fixing the string in the generated values.xml since that was where the error lead me, but every build it was being regenerated from the still invalid strings.xml. Haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for all `'` and `"` in your `string.xml` (and others if any) to be sure that they are all escaped as `\'` and `\"` resp.

For example string `Can't do that` must be escaped `Can\'t do that`

Comment: I know that - except every single time I try to rebuild the project, Android Studio decides to revert that change and give me the same error for some reason.

Comment: Android Studio (gradle actually) re-generates (reverts) that `xml` file from all of your have in your project. Look for all possible string resources in `/src/main/res' folder

Comment: All files should be found and changed in order to fix this problem. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try This in Android Studio Build Clean Project